# Minimum-trust AppDomain cross-calling methods in a full trust AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions, appdomain

I have a minimum-trust `AppDomain` that is calling (across a remoting boundary) methods in a full trust assembly in a full trust `AppDomain`.

However I am getting lots of security exceptions when making these method calls. It would appear that the minimum-trust 'sandbox' is propagating up the stack its minimal security privileges onto the full trust assembly.

Is there a way to get around this beside tagging all my methods in the full trust assembly with `SecurityAction.Assert`'s?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute to the full trust assembly.